# C++ loss of variables

Tags: c++, pointers, mfc, scope

I have a CEdit and I want to extract the data using this.

```
wchar_t *temp = (wchar_t*)dialog.editbox.GetBuffer(0);
dialog.editbox.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Now i want to save this text in a object pointer like this:

```
selectedShape->setText(temp);
```

This work perfect, but only as long as you are in the scope of the method, because when I do a file save later, the text is not in the object anymore.

Does anybody know how I can save this `wchar_t*` for later?

Comment: In a other method. selectedShape is a pointer which is used throughout the app.

Comment: The documentation says, "[Use `ReleaseBuffer` to end use of a buffer allocated by `GetBuffer`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300574(v=vs.60).aspx)." You are using the buffer after releasing it. If you want to keep the buffer valid, don't release your only copy.

Comment: Is `editbox` a CEdit control? CEdit does not have `GetBuffer` & `ReleaseBuffer` member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `temp` pointer is pointing to data that goes out of scope, so you'll need to dynamically allocate memory to store the value. Something like this should work:

```
// Updated to use wstring, thanks praetorian
std::wstring tempStr((wchar_t*)dialog.editbox.GetBuffer(0));
```

Or:

```
int length = /*figure out the length here*/;
wchar_t *temp = new wchar_t[length];
memcpy(temp, dialog.editbox.GetBuffer(0), length*sizeof(wchar_t));
// dont forget to delete it like this: delete [] temp;
```

Comment: `std::string` to hold a `wchar_t` buffer? Try `std::wstring`

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. This is for a school project and I'm obligated to use only char* and wchar_t*. EDIT: Oh I see your edit. Trying it out now

Comment: @HansElsen They're *teaching MFC in school*?  O noes.  Bjarne Stroustrup was lamenting in a presentation recently that he'll go places and they haven't updated their coursework beyond [Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B)...but this is probably even more misguided!

Comment: I tried your solution. It saves my variable thank god, but it has not the right value. It gets messed up at memcpy. temp now contains: L"te췍췍﷽﷽

Comment: @HostileFork Its not the purpuse of learning new concepts, but its learning C++, and we're using MFC as a (lame) method. So not very new skool but it's raising questions like mine, so not totally useless.

Comment: @HansElsen, ok, Im not familiar with the wchar_t type, I think the length is not correct, updating answer.

Comment: @HansElsen Possibly because you're only copying half the string. `memcpy` requires the size in bytes, not number of characters. Use `memcpy(temp, dialog.editbox.GetBuffer(0), length*sizeof(wchar_t));`. Also, since you're dealing with a string, it is advisable to allocate `length + 1` and NULL terminate the string after copying.

Comment: yeah that did the job! Thanks for increasing my knowledge 8-). +1

Comment: @HansElsen happy to help. As HostileFork mentions in his answer, try to avoid using dynamic allocations when possible, so the first option should also work.

Comment: `memcpy` => `std::copy`. Then this kind of errors cannot occur.

Answer (score 2):

As @Prætorian says, your code seems to be missing a step of where you work with a `CString` class whose buffer you are getting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880(v=vs.60).aspx

If at all possible, avoid using dynamic memory solutions.  Instead, pass around your `temp` by value as a CString object that will manage its own memory.  The stock Window `setText` functions take string pointers (which CString can implicitly cast to) and will copy the underlying string data.  If you write your own objects, hold CString objects as members by value.

*(I'll add my usual "The 90s called, they want their framework back" disclaimer here.  [Try Qt](http://qt.digia.com/product/developer-tools/).)*

Comment: +1 for the answer, and another +1 for the comment about the 90s and their framework, and another +1 for suggesting Qt! :)

Comment: Aren't those +1/3rds?  :)  Do try and do as little raw pointer arithmetic and such as you can...anywhere you see `memcpy` you're using C style techniques and not C++.  There's new stuff going on that is making it more efficient; C++11 can even return a giant data structure by value and knows to "move" it instead of "copying" it.  I suggest taking a moment to read this short paper: http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf